# How to script a simple collision using hands in OVRCameraRigInteraction?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

**Summary**
I wrote a simple Class (InteractableObject) to help highlight when my hand is interacting with an object. What is a performant and Idiomatic way to script this interaction?

I'm using the latest version 63 of both "meta all in one sdk" and Interaction SDK"

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/meta-xr-all-in-one-sdk-269657
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/meta-xr-interaction-sdk-264559

**Here is some loose pseudocode to help describe what I"m trying to do.**

```
using UnityEngine;

public class InteractableObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool highlightOnHover = true; // Should the object change appearance when hovered over?
    public Material highlightMaterial;  // Material to use for highlighting

    private Renderer myRenderer;  // Stores a reference to our renderer
    private Material originalMaterial; // Stores the object's original material

    void Start()
    {
        myRenderer = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        originalMaterial = myRenderer.material;
    }

    // Replace with the actual Interactor component type
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        OVRInteractor interactor = collision.collider.GetComponent<OVRInteractor>();
        if (interactor != null)
        {
            HandleInteraction();
        }
    }

    // Replace with the actual Interactor component type
    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        OVRInteractor interactor = collision.collider.GetComponent<OVRInteractor>();
        if (interactor != null)
        {
            HandleInteractionEnd();
        }
    }

    void HandleInteraction()
    {
        Debug.Log("Interactable object collided with OVR hand!");

        if (highlightOnHover)
        {
            myRenderer.material = highlightMaterial;
        }

        // ... Add your custom interaction logic here ...
        // Play sounds, trigger events, etc.
    }

    void HandleInteractionEnd()
    {
        if (highlightOnHover)
        {
            myRenderer.material = originalMaterial; 
        }
    }
}
```